# Problems while formatting SD card

Tags: sd-card, formatting, fdisk

So I've been trying to format an 8 GB [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) on my Ubuntu 11.10. I started with using fdisk and followed the step by step instructions to the letter using the appropriate values from the following site: http://omappedia.org/wiki/SD_Configuration And everything goes as it should up till when I get to the step where you run:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n boot /dev/sdc1
```

I get this

> mkfs.vfat 3.0.9 (31 Jan 2010)
>   mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdc1

And I guess for the sake of complete information, I ran `sudo fdisk -ls`.

and this happens:

> Disk /dev/mapper/sdc1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted). You can find it in the Software center. Open it, and find your device. If you don't need the data, just delete the partition and make another one. It can make a TON of different partitions and partition tables.

Comment: k I'll give it a shot

Comment: Well that didnt work...when it gets to creating the fat32 partition an error pops up. Any ideas

Comment: What is the error? o_O Also, what partition table did you make? If its says something about there not being enough room you can offset it a little.

Comment: Also this might not work if your SD card has to be formatted a certain way with certain partition offsets.

Comment: how do u determine this

Comment: Im not in ubuntu right now... but, Its in one of the menus under "device info" i think... I Could be wrong.